# Indoors-vs-outdoors sensor

Tags: sensor, embedded, robotics

What a near-perfect-accuracy yet dirt-cheap way for a drone or other miniature embedded computer to sense whether it's indoors vs outdoors? Some ideas:

- Geo position sensor if small, low power, and cheap enough
- Light sensor to detect the 60 Hz flicker of electric lights
- Antenna and analog filter to detect EMI typical of occupied buildings
- Echo generator & microphone
- broad-spectrum UV-visible-IR photosensors to discriminate natural vs solar light
- Thermometer, barometer, or other air sensors

Comment: This question would be a good fit for the upcoming [Robotics SE](http://http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/40020). Don't forget to go over there and 'Commit' to the proposal, so we can bring it into existence.

Comment: You forgot the colon after http, in the link. Corrected link:
http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/40020

Comment: Er, it was a test to see if you read it.

Comment: Uh huh ;). Anyways, I did commit.

Comment: Don't you think there's a risk of the Robotics SE cannibalizing the EE SE? I would hate to see the community fracture, and to never know where to best ask a question to get high traffic.

Comment: I hope not. But I think that pure EE questions would be off-topic there, just as robotics questions are really supposed to be off-topic here. So there shouldn't be much overlap really. I saw you committed, thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Light with wavelenght shorter than 300nm is scarce in the output of most types of lightbulbs and it is highly absorbed by typical window glass. On the other hand, it is relatively abundant in sunlight. Therefore a light sensor with a medium/far UV passing filter should do the job with a little bit of calibration. Open windows might confuse it.

---

#### References

- [Solar emission curve](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File%3aSolar_Spectrum.png)
- [Incandescent lamp emission curve](http://physicsed.buffalostate.edu/pubs/TPT/TPTDec99Filament.pdf)
- [Fluorescent lamp emission curve](http://assets.sylvania.com/assets/documents/faq0041-0800.83f1d8de-3fe1-4d24-a209-d95f6cac74b9.pdf)
- [Float glass transmission curve](http://www.pgo-online.com/intl/katalog/curves/whitefl_kurve.html)
- [B270 glass transmission curve](http://www.pgo-online.com/intl/katalog/curves/B270_kurve.html)
- [Soda lime and borosilicate glass transmission curves](http://www.sinclairmfg.com/datasheets/optical3.html)

Comment: Adding on to this, the ambient light sensor method is what smartphones (at least the iPhone) use to know when to auto-adjust the display brightness based on the light conditions. Here is one ambient light sensor you can try: [TEMT6000](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/8348). And here is a brief discussion of that sensor: [Bildr article](http://bildr.org/2011/06/temt6000_arduino/).